# Mapperly RMG023 error: How to specify default value for mapping?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapperly

I am mapping an object (A=>B).  B has a `required` property which is not contained in A, but is available from another source.  How can I create a map and provide this value, such that I do not get an RMG023 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only way is to create an instance mapper, set a property to the additional mapping source and implement an [object factory](https://mapperly.riok.app/docs/configuration/object-factories/) setting all required properties. [Additional mapping parameters](https://github.com/riok/mapperly/issues/103) is an issue requesting what you need, but will probably take some time to implement.